# How to create a theme specific translation of buddypress?

Tags: buddypress, translation, theme-roots

[Originally asked on the BuddyPress forums](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-a-theme-specific-translation/):

For distribution purposes I would like to include my customized buddypress language files in my theme alongside my other language files. No matter what I try though I can only get the language files to display if I copy them over to `wp-content/languages` as described in the [buddypress codex](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/customizing/customizing-labels-messages-and-urls/). I thought that the following would work, but it doesn’t:

```
function load_buddypress_language_files() {
    load_theme_textdomain('buddypress', get_template_directory() . '/lang');
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_buddypress_language_files');
```

This is possible isn't it?

WP: 3.5.1 BP: 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, actions added to `plugins_loaded` hook will not work from theme `functions.php` or any theme file because at that point it will be already fired (too late from theme files).

What you can do is to hook your action into `after_setup_theme` and unload `buddypress` text domain first and then add your custom `buddypress` text domain file. The reason is that WordPress will not load any translation files for text domains that has already been added:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'replace_bp_mofile');

function replace_bp_mofile() {
    $mo_file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/' . sprintf( 'buddypress-%s.mo', get_locale() );
    if (file_exists( $mo_file )) {
        unload_textdomain('buddypress');
        load_textdomain('buddypress', $mo_file);
    }   
}
```